# Как получить значение из каждого объекта и вставить в таблицу

Tags: javascript, html, json

К примеру у меня есть json c данными

```
{
  "01.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "02.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "03.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "04.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "05.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "06.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "07.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "08.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "09.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "10.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "11.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "12.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}}
}
```

как вывести в таблицу одно и тоже значение к примеру `data["01.2020"].sales.cash` со всех объектов  и вставить в таблицу

```
<table border="1" summary="">
    <tr class="sum">
        <th> Общая сумма продаж</th>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

мой js

```
  $.post( "data.txt", function( data ) {

            console.log(data["01.2020"].sales.cash)
            $items = $(".sum td").eq(0); 
            let i = 0; 
            $.each(data["01.2020"].sales.cash, function(key, val) {
                $temp = $items.children().eq(i);
                $temp.append( val );
                i++;
            });

        }
    };
    });
```

Comment: вы читали вообще что такое jquery ? зачем вы подключаете библиотеку, а потом пишите нативные xhr запросы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать например так :

```js
const jsonString = `{
  "01.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "02.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "03.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "04.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "05.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "06.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "07.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "08.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "09.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "10.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "11.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}},
  "12.2020": {"constructions": {"qty": "82288","performance": "80.7","plan": "100465","forecast": "92288","growth": "30.7"}, "sales": {"cash": "464663.45","performance": "72.7","plan": "465445","forecast": "464663.5","growth": "14.2", "average_price": "89.4"}}
}`;

const parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);
const table = document.getElementById('tbl1');

Object.keys(parsedJson).forEach(k => {
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

  cell1.innerHTML = k;
  cell2.innerHTML = parsedJson[k].sales.cash;
})
```

```html
<table border="1" summary="" id="tbl1">
  <tr class="sum">
    <th> Дата</th>
    <th> Общая сумма продаж</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```